# Using Kmeans on my data.

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I think I understand how the kmeans algorithm works, but I'm having a lot of trouble modeling it into a format with my data.

I'm looking for a way to get the most similar games based on my inputs.

example:

```
 Original_Game has n Similar_Games.  Similar_Games has n Genres, Themes, Tropes. 
 Original_Game1 has n Similar_Games.  Similar_Games has n Genres, Themes, Tropes.
```

I'm thinking kmeans can tell me which of the Similar_Games are most similar to both Original_Game and Original_Game1.  But I don't know how to organize this data on a 2d plot, if I'm not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Can you compute *means*? If you cannot compute reasonable means on your data, you cannot use k-means.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use k-means on data that:

- can reasonably be represented numerically
- is not overly discrete (don't run k-means on binary vectors!)
- where all dimensions have approximately the same meaning (i.e. 1 cm on x axis approx 1 cm on y axis)
- where you can compute *means*
- where the means *decrease* variance, otherwise it might not converge

K-means is easy to understand, but just does not work on arbitrary data.

You can lessen some of these restrictions by going for example to k-medoids / partitioning around medoids (PAM). This is a closely related algorithm that does away with most of these restrictions, at the cost of usually being a lot slower.

Comment: I guess I should close this question.  This has helped, but I just went another route.  It jsut ended up requiring more work on my part. 

Sorry about that.